# Touchpad Gestures on Linux

Tags: interface, navigation

Hey there fellow Blender heads,

I'm making the jump to Ubuntu from Mac. Blender's support for the Mac touchpad was really great.  Is there a way to setup the equivalent in Linux?

Comment: I run Blender on an aging laptop under Ubuntu sometimes.  It is a joy to figure out little obstacles like this, but it can get time consuming.  My first suggestion is to google the functionality that you want to make happen and see what you can dig up.
  If you can provide any more info on the functionality you seek, that might help readers respond more specifically to your needs.

Comment: On 3.4.x on my arch linux installation (libinput/plasma) mouse gestures works out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I will show you how to get wayland-like trackpad gestures for Xorg (X11).I was done in linux - Ubuntu 22.04, and I'm not sure if it will work for any newer versions or not. I assume it will eventually work, but I don't know what the latest version the extension is at.

COMMANDS:

> sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade; sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
> gnome-shell-extensions gnome-shell-extension-manager

We have just a app called extension manager. Now, press windows key look for extension manager and open it. Will see to option there at navigation one installed and second one is browse. click on browse and search for the x11 gestures and click install.Now just run below commands.

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:touchegg/stable

> sudo apt install touchegg

Now, we have install touchegg, run one more command for checking wether or not we install gestures successfully.

> systemctl status touchegg

look for the status if `Active: active (running)`. we have successfully installed the gestures. use your three finger now.